# Export data from ODBC to CSVs or similar

Tags: export, csv, odbc

I have a SQL Anywhere 5 database which I can currently access through ODBC. I managed to open it with Access but when I used Access to export text files it would truncate the data.

Is there a way with Access or any other tool to easily export all tables to a bunch of CSV files with field names as the first row and the table names as the file names, or something like that?

I'm not familiar with Access (which is installed in a language I don't understand), ODBC or even Windows in general; so, don't hesitate to point to obvious solutions, I probably missed them.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an [ISQL CLient](http://manuals.sybase.com/onlinebooks/group-pbarc/conn5/sqlug/@Generic__BookTextView/2168;pt=1441) and then export to CSV as [discussed in SO HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4355080/sybase-sql-anywhere-how-to-output-data-from-isql-to-csv-file-with-headings).

Comment: Would that include field names? Any way to avoid doing it table by table?

Comment: This will not include field names "SELECT * FROM SomeTable;
OUTPUT TO 'C:\temp\sometable.csv' FORMAT ASCII DELIMITED BY ';' QUOTE ''" but you will have to do it table by table.  Let me have a poke around and see is there a better solution.

Comment: There is also [this](http://sqlanywhere-forum.sybase.com), which may be of use at some point.